# Picklist value monitor

Tags: custom-object, picklist, record-type, dependent-picklist, record

I have a custom object X where I have lookup of Y. Now in Y there are three values(Y1,Y2,Y3). For Y1, a picklist values in X would come up as X1,X2. For Y2, picklist values in X would come up as Xa,Xb,Xc etc. Can I achieve that without creating any VF page or govern that by record types like for Y1 product X will have recordtype XY1. For Y2, will have XY2 etc. Anyother solution here? Please help.

Comment: Are you just asking how to set up a picklist dependency?

Comment: Can I do that depending on a lookup field value? That field is not coming up in controlling field.

Comment: What you are asking for isn't possible using a picklist and a lookup as you describe. What is the use case that you are trying to solve for? (Can it be described with less obscurity than the question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that your X records are created only from the Related list on Y detail page,  then you can override new button on related list of X object. Using this custom overriden custom button(execute JavaScript n sending record type in redirect url) on related list,  u can auto select the record type of X depending on Y's value,  and will skip record type selection of X object. Now on the edit page of X,  you would already have limited picklist values that u would had made dependent on X's record type.

Comment: But I dont want to create a separate page. How can I call a record type by override button. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I Had done this in my last org. No need created VF page as such. This javascript button may help you.

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}  {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var RecordTypeQuery = "Select Id from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Task' And DeveloperName = 'Task'";  var resultID = sforce.connection.query(RecordTypeQuery);  var rec =resultID.getArray("records");  window.open("/00T/e?what_id={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&RecordType=" + rec[0].Id + "&ent=Task","_parent");